# Logarithmic Graph in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, graph

I want to create a logarithmic graph in WPF. X axis ranges from 10 to 20,000 and Y axis ranges from -20 to 20. X axis division are not uniform, they are based on some log formulas. 
Since I am new to WPF, I don't know which approach is good to create graph in WPF. Is there any control available in WPF to create logarithmic graphs or Is there any other solutions to draw it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of chart controls in wpf toolkit.
Other custom build charts are also available.please go through the links below

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Chart-Control-in-WPF-c9727c28

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196502/WPF-Toolkit-Charting-Controls-Line-Bar-Area-Pie-Co

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/torstenmandelkow/archive/2013/05/06/free-modernui-charts-for-wpf-windows-store-apps-und-silverlight-published.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out Oxyplot. It supports logarithmic plotting.https://github.com/ylatuya/oxyplot/tree/master/Source/OxyPlot.Wpf.

Here is some sample code, generated using Oxyplot's ExampleBrowser (highly recommended!!), which is also available through GitHub.

```
    [Example("Untitled")]
    public static PlotModel Untitled()
    {
        var plotModel1 = new PlotModel();
        var logarithmicAxis1 = new LogarithmicAxis();
        logarithmicAxis1.Maximum = 1000000;
        logarithmicAxis1.Minimum = 1;
        logarithmicAxis1.Title = "Log axis";
        logarithmicAxis1.UseSuperExponentialFormat = true;
        plotModel1.Axes.Add(logarithmicAxis1);
        var logarithmicAxis2 = new LogarithmicAxis();
        logarithmicAxis2.Maximum = 10000;
        logarithmicAxis2.Minimum = 0.001;
        logarithmicAxis2.Position = AxisPosition.Bottom;
        logarithmicAxis2.Title = "Log axis";
        logarithmicAxis2.UseSuperExponentialFormat = true;
        plotModel1.Axes.Add(logarithmicAxis2);
        return plotModel1;
    }
```